# Error when store data to database using postman

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to Store data to data base using this method

```
public function store(Request $request){
     
        $this->validate($request,[
            'type_id' => 'required',
            'room_number' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ]);
        Rooms::create([
            'type_id' => $request->type_id,
            'room_number' => $request->room_number,
            'status' => $request->status,
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Success!!',
            'data' => Rooms::all()
        ]);
    }
```

I'm using Postman to insert my data, but an there is error on my postman, its says

> ```
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
> a foreign key constraint fails (`hotel`.`rooms`, CONSTRAINT `rooms_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN 
> KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `type` (`type_id`)) (SQL: insert into `rooms` 
> (`type_id`, `room_number`, `status`, `updated_at`,`created_at`) values (1, 1, 
> available, 2023-01-22 06:21:07, 2023-01-22 06:21:07))  in file E:\Laravel\hotel-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 760
> ```

And this is my database structure

[image: pos]

if this error related to my model, this is my `Rooms` Model

```
class Rooms extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'rooms';
    protected $primaryKey = 'room_id';
    public $fillable = [
        'room_number', 'status','type_id'
    ];

    public function Type(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class, 'type_id');
    }
}
```

and this is my `type` model

```
class Type extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'type';
    protected $primaryKey = 'type_id';
    public $fillable = [
       'price', 'desc', 'photo'
    ];

    public function Room(){
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class, 'room_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values in the hotel types table? Does that table got the value of 1?

Comment: can you add your migration code ?